# How to set inherit specific css for element

Tags: html, css, inheritance

I looked in the questions but could not find it. I want to inherit just one of css for element `<a>`. E.g. div1 css or body css . But It sets css of div2. How to set inherit specific css for element  `<a>`. I tried { color:inherit } , a { /*color*/ !important;} , a { color:none;} .  But it does not work.

```css
body {color: red;}
.div1{  color:yellow;}
.div2{  color:blue;}
a { /*color*/ !important;  }
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="div1">
     <div class="div2">
  <a>Test Test Test</a>
         <p>bla bla bla<p>
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question at all: what color do you want the `<a>` to have?

Comment: `inherit` inherits styles directly from the parent element. There are many different options available to you here, so I've voted to close this as *too broad*. If you're looking for a specific outcome then please edit your question to narrow down what you're looking for.

Comment: color of body or div1

Comment: body {color: red;}
.div1{  color:yellow;}
.div2{  color:blue;}
a { /*color*/ !important;  }

I have a few referenced css in my html page. E.g o But I just want to use body or div1 css class. Is it possible?

Comment: Then use `.div1 a { color: yellow; }`, it has greater precedence than `.div2 { color: blue; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont define color for `p` and `a`,them get value her parent(blue) by default.so you must define color for it like: `a {color:red}` or use of `CSS variables` like this:

```css
body {
    color: red;
  --color:red;
}

.div1 {
    color:yellow;
}

.div2 {
    color:blue;
}

.div2 a { 
    color: var(--color) !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">
        <a>Test Test Test</a>
        <p>bla bla bla<p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I cant change css of body,div1,div2.  Because, there are too many other elements that use them

Comment: @HurelKöseer,CAN YOU CHANGE HTML CODE?

Comment: i can change my html code. But i want to change element css.  
E.g-  a { color: div1 color....... }

Comment: @HürelKöseer , look to my answer well, i change css only.

Comment: what is the different between a {color : red} and a {color: var...}. It is not inheritance. For example , I have two css library ,bootsrapt.css and xyz.css. I have a button. get button color is blue from bootsrapt. yellow color from xyz.css.  My button color is yellow. Because xyz override bootsrapt. I want to get only button color from bootsrapt. But get button's other css from xyz.css . is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

With *.div1* and *.div2* selectors you are defining the behaviour of specific classes in your html document; instead with the a selector *a* you are defining the behaviour for **all a tags** in it. 
By default, a **class** selector as *.div1* or*.div2* has always the priority towards a generic **tag** selector as *a* is.
Finally, your text is blue instead of red because div2 is a inner part of div1, so the css rules of div1 will be overwritten by div2.

Comment: I didn't quite understand. Could you show me in the html/css code?

Comment: @HurelKoseer  If you can't change css rules defined for body, div1 and div2 and you should consider to assign a **id** to the specific div2 that you want different from others *div2* elements. So, defining rules, with a *id* selector you can override the color rule for div2, i.e.

    #particular_div2{
         color: yellow;  /*or every color you prefer*/
    }

Comment: @HurelKoseer Also, if you don't want modify your stylesheet at all, you could write styling rules in the html element directly e.g. <div class="div2" style="color:yellow;">... </div>. In this way, you should be able to override the color rule defined in your stylesheet.

Comment: Could you show me in the html/css code (E.g Code Snippet)?

Comment: @HurelKooser look to my first comment for css. For html rewrite your div2 as <div class="div2" id="particular_div2">...</div>

Comment: Can I just want to use  css page ? Eg  a { /*color*/ !important;  } . Is it possible?

Comment: @HureelKooser did you try with a{ color: yellow !important;} or with .div2 a{color:yellow;}

Comment: i didn' try a{color:yellow !important} . Because I do not want to write that way. Eg ==>  i want to do ==>  a {  div1 color ?? }

Comment: @HurelKoseer In my opinion(but i'm not sure at all) it's impossible to do what you're trying to do. I presume the reason you don't want specify a particular color( trying to retrieve div1 color ) is because your div1 color can change because of script. In this case can't you  simply change also the color of the **a** tag in the **div2** div?

Comment: I think this there is a way that. But i cant find it

Comment: @HurelKooser In any case, my advise is : edit your question. Lots of comment to understand what you are really trying to do.